# How to finetune map function and avoid using flatten

Tags: ruby, algorithm, functional-programming, permutation

I have the following code to list all possible permutations of a give string. But due to my awkward list (ruby array) manipulation and limited knowledge on functional programming, I have to use flatten to get the result array. It is pretty much a hack. How can I refactor the code and avoid using (abusing) flatten?

```
class String
  def remove_char_at(i)
    if i==0
      self[1..-1]
    else
      self[0..i-1] + self[i+1..-1]
    end
  end
end

def permute(str,prefix="")

  if str.size==0
    prefix
  else
    str.chars.each_with_index.map do |s,i|
        permute(str.remove_char_at(i),prefix+s)
    end.flatten
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find intresting things about functional programming in first chapters of [SICP](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Structure-Interpretation-Computer-Electrical-Engineering/dp/0262510871/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1344245396&sr=8-1)

```
def permute2(str,prefix="")

  if str.size==0
    [prefix] #revise for concatenate with memo
  else
    str.chars.each_with_index.inject([]) do |memo, ary|
        s = ary[0]
        i = ary[1]
        memo += permute2(str.remove_char_at(i),prefix+s) #memoize
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: in `block in permute2': can't convert String into Array (TypeError)

Comment: I adjust the return value to an array. and now it is working.

Comment: Though I kinda find my original version without the accumulator easier to understand...

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has done much of the hard work for you.  To get all permutations for a string, myString, do the following:

```
myString.split('').permutation.map(&:join).uniq
```

This splits the string components into an array; gets all the permutations of the array; joins those back into strings; weeds out duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. But I am more keen on some refactoring advice on my ruby code so that I can get some clues to hone my understanding on functional programming.

Answer (score 2):

```
class String
  def remove_char_at(i)
    if i==0
      self[1..-1]
    else
      self[0..i-1] + self[i+1..-1]
    end
  end
end
```

can be refactored as follows by using `...` instead of `..`

```
class String
  def remove_char_at(i)
    self[0...i] + self[i+1..-1]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm specifically answering the *How can I refactor the code and avoid using (abusing) flatten?* part:

Instead of `map` + `flatten`, you can just use [flat_map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map) which was introduced in 1.9.2.